# Open website in browser directly when http://localhost is input

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am using xampp and i have a website in htdocs.

The home page `home.html` is in a folder `website -> website/home.html`. I want to host that website in xampp, so my question is, how to access the home page `home.html` directly.

Is there any modification that need to be done?

Comment: `http://localhost` would point at your own machine. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MarcB I think he means that home.html is loaded when going to localhost

Comment: What i want is that when i input http://localhost into my browser,it should display the home.html

Comment: edit `vhost.conf` or better yet google `edit httpd-vhost.conf xampp`

Comment: This has nothing to do with php though.

Comment: @kevinabelita i don't have knowledge of how to edit the vhost.conf..can you help me

Comment: You might want to look at `virtual hosts`, so you can do `mysite.dev` and point it to your local site.

Comment: you can check out this [source](http://austin.passy.co/2012/setting-up-virtual-hosts-wordpress-multisite-with-xampp-on-windows-7/), it gives a good detail on this matter

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to move your home.html to the htdocs folder (just simple move it outside your website folder) and then make sure to rename it as index.html.

Since index.(php/html) would be automatically be opened once you access your localhost.
But take note this will replace the XAMPP's default index page which is not a problem (unless you want to make use of it).

Comment: I have tried it and its giving me the page but but when am clicking on a link,Error 404 is displayed.

Comment: When you received an Error 404 it means "Page not found".
Therefore the link you would want to visit doesn't exist, double check the href of your anchor tag if it is still pointing correctly to the location/file that you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want `home.html` to open as the default page when browsing to `http://localhost`? If so, you'll want to add home.html as a Directory Index file. In standard Apache HTTPD server configuration, you'd just look for a block looking like:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
</IfModule>
```

Just add `home.html` to the end of the DirectoryIndex line, so you'd get:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php home.html
</IfModule>
```

The location of your httpd.conf file, where you'll need to make this change, depends on your XAMPP installation.

If this is not your question, you'll need to provide more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be preferable to change virtual hosts, a simpler solution would be to use an HTML Redirect. Create, in the htdocs folder, an index.html file with this line in it

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://localhost/website/home.html">
```

(assuming that localhost is reachable and the structure of the directory is htdocs/website/home.html)